# Getting 403 Forbidden in Linkedin API V2 while querying for AdSupplyForecast

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j

I am using the LinkedIn API V2 and I am trying to query the AdSupplyForecast endpoint from my company profile. I am using the following tutorial to build the request using Targeting Criteria V2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ad-supply-forecasts

This is the request information:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adSupplyForecasts?q=criteriaV2&campaignType=TEXT_AD&account=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A2560807&timeRange=(start:1541691210720,end:1544283210720)&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Agenders:List(urn%3Ali%3Agender%3AMALE,urn%3Ali%3Agender%3AFEMALE)))))) HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
```

This is the response information:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
X-Restli-Gateway-Error: true
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 16:33:31 GMT
X-Li-Fabric: prod-lor1
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: prod-efr5
X-LI-Proto: http/1.1
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=OB68:g=1068:u=602:i=1541694811:t=1541781211:s=AQGBKJna3VcsX87YCodNIDqiNNTr_AKi"
X-LI-Route-Key: "b=OB68:g=1068:u=602:i=1541694811:t=1541781211:s=AQGBKJna3VcsX87YCodNIDqiNNTr_AKi"
X-LI-UUID: FGtPJ0MzZRXgVVzfeCsAAA==
message:"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/account]"
```

When I am trying to query the AdBudgetPricing endpoint with the same account everything is working as expected.

Comment: could you share your permissions of the linkedin application.

Comment: Sure, here you go:
r_ad_campaign, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social, w_share

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

seems like this request refuses to accept the account parameter in the url, could you remove this one ?

**Edit:**
examples for the targeting criteria containing an include and an exclude in all examples.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-examples

Comment: If I try to use this endpoint without an account parameter, I get the following error: Parameter 'account' is required.
This happens because I am using the targetingCriteriaV2 object in which the account property is required. This is a new API change so using this endpoint without an account parameter is not an option.

Comment: are you by any chance working with ruby on rails ? because that is the only thing i can imagine giving such an error aswell. apart from linkedin?

Comment: Nope I am not using Ruby. I am working with Java, but it wouldn't matter I suppose.

Comment: check the edit i made to the answer, it is a structure for the tragetCriteria. and in this structure they always define an include and an exclude. try adding the exclude.

Comment: Adding an exclude targeting criteria is not mandatory as you can see from the examples but just to make sure I tried adding an exclude targeting criteria but unfortunately that did not solve the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: yeah i know it was a long shot. but at this point long shots is what you need to try because your code is exactly the same. i will look some more if i can find the time.